# Django : An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am getting this error when i add a specific line in the post request.

views.py

```
class LoginVerify(View):
    print('login')
    email =""
    pswd = ""
    username =""

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        print("post called")
        self.email = request.POST['email']
        self.pswd = request.POST['pswd']
        self.username = User.objects.get(email=self.email).username
        return HttpResponse("Invalid user")
```

If I add `self.username = User.objects.get(email=self.email).username` then it is showing the error, otherwise it is working fine.

Why it is happening, how can I solve this?

Comment: I'm guessing there is an error (logs? debug mode?) that you're not seeing. Did you import `User`? Does the user with that email exist? It looks like you're returning an 'invalid user' response, but you don't catch a `User.DoesNotExist` exception in the previous line, so I'm not sure how that's supposed to work.

Comment: Yes i have imported the user model. It is working fine in shell. but throws error while running.

Comment: What is the value of self.email? I also agree with Hamish that you should try to catch the DoesNotExist exception. I would also try to log the exception or wrap the whole thing up in the free version of New Relic to see what it spits out.  NewRelic is usually a nice thing to add in any case.

Answer (score 8):

I usually get this when running on my local machine in debug mode usually happens if the server responds to a request and the client has already closed the connection. You may ignore the error or use a different production server such as gunicorn which has better server socket handling. FYI i see this error on python 2.7

Comment: The same is observed on python3.6 version also