# Error in Django execution,AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django project which uses Django+Django Rest Framework+Djoser (token based auth).

The project runs perfectly and I am able to GET and POST desired data's with backend.

But a strange error hits the running terminal randomly after certain interval and during some GET /POST operation, it never cause work interruption as terminal do not stop running.

I have attached the minified error screenshot for the reference.

I am unable to identify the place of error/cause of error to debug.

[image]

complete error code as mention below:

```
[10/Jun/2020 00:01:19] "GET /media/tracks/Kalimba_FXkucKr.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 200 5382144
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\socketserver.py", line 796, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[10/Jun/2020 00:01:19] "GET /media/tracks/Kalimba_FXkucKr.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55650)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\socketserver.py", line 796, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\djangorest\jun4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\djangorest\jun4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\djangorest\jun4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\djangorest\jun4\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "c:\users\dell\desktop\pythonfiles\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in
close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
[10/Jun/2020 00:01:29] "GET /songs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2211
```

Comment: Please check if this error appears just after closing a window?

Comment: Actually not after that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619278/django-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-mach

Comment: Thankls I will checkout it

Comment: Do you find solution?

Comment: It was problem with database, I removed the database and applied migrations again